# AutoMount ext2 SD-card on Huawei U8350 (Android 2.2.2)

Tags: root-access, mount, init.d

On the Huawei U8350 (Android 2.2.2) the init scripts all appear to be in the root partition -- which actually is a ram disk (initramfs), so any changes to it aren't persistent across reboots.

Is there a way to run a command at boot-time to mount an ext2 partition on the External-SD without unpacking and reflashing the root image?

Comment: I think there might be a place where the system could be looking for some `init.local` or equivalent.

Comment: Yes, this is where we might find the answer - or you know, maybe where the system calls some command that uses a config file that I might be able to edit, thereby allowing me to call some other command.. This is the kind of thing I would be looking for.

Comment: Keith, we deal with end-user questions here. And how many end-users do you thing fiddle this way with their root partition? :) I never did, and never had the need for it. So no, I wasn't aware of that fact. I'd rather consider this a development question (borderlining power-users, or somebody had already close-voted) -- and thus you find [the relevant topic on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768103/make-persistent-changes-to-init-rc). But, as said, you might check the `init.rc` whether it contains any hooks (makes calls to files outside the ramdisk).

Comment: I think this is perfectly on-topic.  I've done nonsense like this all the time (although nothing than can specifically help you here I don't think).  Writing a script might be somewhat development related but the concern is an end-user one.  In any case, I've cleaned up the comments here a little.

Comment: As for the problem at hand: Is it necessary to run do this in an init script?  Tasker or something may be able to simply do this immediately after the system boots.